# Updating the Quick launch node titles only using Power-Shell in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, powershell, navigation

I am trying to update the title of quick lunch navigation in my SharePoint sub sites. Since there are hundred of Sites, scripting sounds a better idea. I wrote a script but it is not updating the titles. 
here is my script

```
$StartWeb="https://nichdmossptl1/projects/recordsmanagement"
$subsites = ((Get-SPWeb $StartWeb).Site).allwebs | ?{$_.url -like   "$StartWeb*"} 
foreach($subsite in $subsites)
{
$navigationNode=$subsite.Navigation.QuickLaunch
$Documentnode = $navigationNode | where { $_.Title -like  "Documents" }
$Travelnode= $Documentnode.children | where { $_.Title -like   "Travel_Documents" }}

$Documentnode.Title="Final Docs"
$Travelnode.Title="Travel_Records";
$subsite.update()
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$Documentnode.Update()` and `$Travelnode.Update()`

Comment: Also, don't forget to dispose